# What is the name of this probability distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

The distribution is $P(\Theta=\theta)= c\cdot \theta^k\cdot(1-\theta)^{n-k}$, where c is a constant (to make this integrate to 1), and $\theta$ goes from 0 to 1.

Note that the support is $\theta$

I had it written down as the Beta distribution, but apparently is it neither the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution, nor the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

It arises when you have a coin, with uniform prior for the coin bias, and you toss it n times, getting k heads. This is then the posterior of the bias.

Comment: It is not a probability, but a probability density evaluated at $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

It's a $Beta(k+1;n-k+1)$

the constant is known

$c=\frac{\Gamma(k+1+n-k+1)}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(n-k+1)}=\frac{\Gamma(n+2)}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(n-k+1)}=\frac{(n+1)!}{k!(n-k)!}=(n+1)\binom{n}{k}$

In fact the $Beta(a;b)$ has the following density

$$\frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{ \Gamma(a)\Gamma(a)}x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}$$

where

- $x$ is the variable in $[0;1]$
- $a,b$ are the parameters, both $>0$

The Noprmalization constant $C$ can be easily calculate as showed, without solving the integral.

As you are studying Bayesian Statistic, your distribution is applied to the parameter $\theta$ (wich is your actual variable)

Remember that in Bayesian Statistic the parameter of the model has its own density

Comment: I thought the Beta was a distribuition with 2 integer parameters, while the function I ask about is one with 1 real parameter. This makes a difference when defining the distribution, right?

Comment: @josinalvo : I wrote some edit in the answer, replying to your comment